# Creating a matrix for a given value of a given value - For loop issues

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I'm not sure if the title is very clear.

What I am trying to do is analyze a huge amount of data and produce a singular matrix for each ID.

The data comes in the form:

```
1001 00101 150

1001 00102 146

1001 00103 145

......

1001 19401 178

1001 19402 194

ID(1:4) Day(6:8) Half hour within a 24 hour period (9:10) Usage(12:end)

e.g ID=1001 Day=001 Half Hour=01 Usage=150
```

The `ID`, `Day` and `Half hour` values follow a strict pattern however the usage is the measured value.

I am trying to output

```
ID Value - Average usage per half hour

1001 01 150
1001 02 160
1001 03 173
1001 04 194
.... .. ...
1001 48 150
.... .. ...
1100 48 147
```

I've broken down the data into each specific component, however I am having trouble outputting the data into the average usage for each half hour, constantly getting trapped in for loops with no end product.

My base code currently examines the first line and extracts each component

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);
ID=tline(1:4);
disp(ID);

Day=tline(6:8);
disp(Day);

HalfHour=tline(9:10);
disp(HalfHour);

Usage=tline(12:end);
disp(Usage);
```

However I am really struggling to amplify this to the entire data set and produce the specified output.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Output format:
1001 01 146
1001 02 150

Comment: Edit your question and add a minimal working example.